# Unable to change draggable mode

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a box in  this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/C8Uce/6/ - that I've made draggable.  When I hit the Snap button I'd like to change the draggable mode to snap to a 50x50 grid, but it's not working.

```
$(function() {
    $('#box').draggable();

    $('#snap').click(function() {
        $('#box').draggable('option',grid, [50,50]);        
    });
});
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what is `grid` here? where you defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes around grid:

Change your initialization to:

```
$('#box').draggable('option','grid', [50,50]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Uce/7/)

With something like this, the console can be your best friend.  It may have led you directly to the problem:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: grid is not defined
```